# An issue with SEO Ultimate

Tags: plugins, 404-error

I'm using SEO Ultimate.

The 404 monitor module is reporting several 404 errors. The errors are reported for urls that do not exist; 3 of them did exist as drafts but were never published.

I checked my xml sitemap, but no luck there. Additionally, the link checker is not showing any broken links.

Anyone experienced with SEO Ultimate who can point me in the right direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the referring URL and the user agent.  Usually these are caused by robots that found a link to the draft or happened to be scanning your site while you were previewing the posts.  I wouldn't worry about it unless it was an actual user that was getting the error.